# How to save array values with configWriter in Magento 2 core config data?

Tags: magento2, array, core-config-data, savedata

I want to save some data which is in array form and used this to save array but it will save Array keyword in this How to save array values with this.

$this->configWriter->save('my/path/whatever1',  $newdata, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);

Comment: Could you please show sample data in the array.

Comment: Prits, i thing you have do json_encode and save in core_config table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save array in config database you can convert array to serialized string.

Inject Serializer Class in your constructor.

```
public function __construct( ...,
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer) {
  /*** You other code ***/
  $this->serializer = $serializer;
}
```

Use the `serialize()` to convert array to serialized string.

```
$serializedData = $this->serializer->serialize($newdata);
$this->configWriter->save('my/path/whatever1', $serializedData, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
```

You can convert the serialized string back to array wherever you wanna use the value as

```
$arrData = $this->serializer->unserialize($serializedData);
```

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response.
How to save the data with this data as an array value not want to log that ? @Abdul

Comment: Please find the updated answer.